# This site can’t be reached - django setup

Tags: django

I'm starting working with django and try to setup new project and after the command "py manage.py runserver"
Everything working and I get this address http://127.0.0.1:8000/
and when I try to enter this address I get that message " This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect".

What I need to fix ?

Thanks

Comment: are you running this locally on your machine, or on a remote server?

Comment: I'm running this locally

Comment: On settings.py check allowed hosts. Try this: ALLOWED_HOSTS =["*"]

Comment: are you including the port 8000 in your url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing port 8000 in your url

**"This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect".**

Check again, if it still doesn't works try using, **python manage.py runserver 8000**

You can refer here too [change port for development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557849/django-development-server-not-working)